# Перенос данных с одной таблицы в другую с разной структурой

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mariadb

Есть исходная таблица А1 - в которой следующая структура: Имя/Фамилия/Регион/Индекс
Есть обновленная таблица А2 - в которой доработанная структура: Имя/Фамилия/Номер телефона/Регион/Статус

Есть ли какие-то сервисы, которые позволят совершить подобный перенос данных из БД А1 в А2?

Спасибо всем

Comment: Невозможно "перенести" данные, которых в исходной таблице нет.

Comment: для выборки данных из таблица есть оператор `SELECT`. для вставки в другую - `INSERT`. Дляобновления - UPDATE, и возможно пригодится JOIN. А задача ваша не ясна.